# Cant send response with "POST" method on js node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, backend

Im trying to create a small login page.
My idea is to send the login data to the server who will check the username and the password and then send a response to the client saying that his login was found.

Here is the server:

```
const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    let data;
    if (request.method == 'POST') {
      console.log('POST');
      const chunks = [];
      request.on("data", (chunk) => {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });
      request.on("end", () => {
        console.log("all parts/chunks have arrived");
        data = JSON.parse(chunks.toString())
        console.log(data);
      });
      response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
      response.write("Hello")
      response.end()
    }
})

const port = 3300
const host = '//////////'
server.listen(port, host)
console.log(`Listening at http://${host}:${port}`)
```

And here the client:

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='http://///////:3300';
Http.open("POST", url, "This is a test");
Http.send(JSON.stringify({username : Id.value, password : Pw.value}));
```

I have tried writing the respone but it causes errors.

What can I do to reply to the client?

(Vanilla Js Node/Javascript)

Comment: Would you please provide more details and any error which thrown?

Comment: I suggest you use middleware so you don't have the process the raw POST data yourself.

Comment: `chunks.toString()` should be `chunks.join('')`. You're adding a `,` between each chunk, so it's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if im right but your url is http://///////3300 with 9 slashes
but in the server your host is ////////// with 10 slashes
maybe this is the problem

Comment: Thats just censored because thats where my ip is.